# Why is declaration of javascript function not possible inside of document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it not possible to declare a pure JavaScript function inside a jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){  }` body?

Is it because `.ready()` is already a function? In pure JavaScript you can have inner functions, right?

Comment: Sure you can declare functions inside of the callback body..? Can you post an example where it doesn't work for you?

Comment: You absolutely can declare a function inside document.ready. What is the problem? I would assume it's related to scope

Comment: this is not a good practice. what exactly that you wanna do?

Comment: @AjayKumar Declaring a function inside the callback is just fine practice - it keeps things non-global, for one

Comment: @CertainPerformance and you know the difference between calling a function and implementing it and defining it? right?

Comment: @AjayKumar Sure..? Declaring a function and then calling it later is perfectly fine

Comment: Usually this is perceived as a problem when you intend to use functions declared there via traditional "onfoo=something()" event handling. Because you're using jQuery anyway, it's generally a much much better idea to use jQuery to bind event handlers. That can all be done from inside the "ready" handler function.

Comment: I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed define a function inside the body of the `ready` callback function. So I assume you're just having trouble accessing a function you've defined there. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
    function test1()
    {
        console.log("test1 function was called");
    }
    function test2()
    {
        console.log("test2 function was called");
    }
    test1(); // works
});
test2(); // does not work - Can't access the scope where test2 was defined.
```

When a `function` is the property of an object it can be referred to as a `method`. `ready` is a method that takes a function as an argument and this function is called a `callback function`, because `ready` will "call it back" after the html document has fully loaded.

`test1` and `test2` (above) are [function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_declaration) and they're only accessible within the call-back function passed to the ready method: since I call `test2()` outside of that scope, it fails.

In javascript, "inner functions" (as you call them) are called [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Click that to learn more about lexical scoping.

Comment: you are implementing the methods not declaring. google the difference between declare and implement.

Comment: in this case it would be declaring + implementing. I think in JavaScript you cannot just declare a function. It is always implementing.

Comment: @SteveClever we can do declaration on js level. please check out my answer.

Comment: The interesting thing is that he is talking about  _pure JavaScript function_ so he must understands about scoping, but my bets are also on some problem with scope

Answer (score -2):

The ready() method is used to make a function available after the document is loaded. Whatever code you write inside the $(document ).ready() method will run once the page DOM is ready to execute JavaScript code.